# PHP form passing vars

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to pass vars from a form using drop down lists, that are populated by a query. It currently goes to **result.php**

```
<form action="result.php" method="post">

<SELECT NAME=Model class="normal"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Phone
<?=$model_o?> 
</SELECT> 

<SELECT NAME=Mins  class="small"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Mins
<?=$minutes_o?> 
</SELECT> 

<SELECT NAME=Texts class="small"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Texts
<?=$texts_o?> 
</SELECT> 

<SELECT NAME=Freegifts class="big"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Choose Free Gifts 
<?=$freegifts_o?> 
</SELECT> 

<SELECT NAME=Network class="normal"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Network 
<?=$network_name_o?> 
</SELECT> 

<SELECT NAME=Merchant class="normal"> 
<OPTION VALUE=0>Contract/Prepay 
<?=$merchant_category_o?> 
</SELECT> 
<br>
<button type="submit" value="search phones" class="red"><span>Sumbit</span></button>

</form>
```

However, what I want it to do is pass any variables from each drop down to the URL, only if a option is selected.

For example, if Model is selected it will pass the variable on to the URL when submit is select e.g. **result.php?model=iphone** and if both a model and mins is selected the URL would something like e.g. **result.php?model=iphone&mins=500**

I hope this makes sense as I am having difficulties explaining what I am actually trying to active.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think you can do what you're looking for. But you can ignore any zero values in your code so this really shouldn't be something you need.

Comment: what are these doing? <?=$model_o?> ..also change the method to 'get'

Comment: not with pure php, you would need to use javascript

Comment: @techjunkie.css they look like php short tags where `<?=$var?>` is equivalent to `<?php echo $var ?>`

Comment: Shouldn't you be closing your `<option>` elements? e.g. `<OPTION VALUE=0>Network</OPTION> 
<?=$network_name_o?>`

Comment: @Kasapo I never knew that cool!

Comment: @AdamLynch I would guess that the `<?=$var?>` contains closing markup

Comment: Javascript will do it before submitting form, you should use it if you need those url before submit. However, urls can be given by php after form is processed at server (filled and submitted first), with php it is fairly easy to combine values.

Comment: ya know , we have been using lowercase tags in HTML since .. emm .. 1999th

Comment: @SupremeDud I'm going to guess it doesn't. Aside from being unintuitive, the rest of the markup isn't exactly consistent or strict.

Comment: @techjunkie.css Yup they're nice. I like them but just in case you ever decide to use them and run into an error, note that many server configurations disable short tags (as I found last year after pushing a website changes into the  production environment for the first time at my new job... result was lots of exposed php code and a very broken website!) and don't give good error messages about it (none in my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using GET, you can't have it *only* send form fields that have data associated with them.  Using GET will send everything about the form, including all fields, even if they don't have any data.  Are you able to parse it with Javascript or perhaps use POST instead?

**Clarification**
I say you're using GET despite your form tag indicating POST because of your follow up (result.php?model....).

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to remove any variables with zero values on submission, therefore they would not reach result.php (including the URL) as they wouldn't be in the `$GET` array.

You could engineer result.php so that if there are no zero values found it operates as normal but if any are found, a new URL is built containing only the other non-zero variables and result.php then could redirect back to itself.

To be honest, I wouldn't do any of the above. Since each of the drop-down menus have an option with a value of zero to begin with, you could simply ignore all zero values received in result.php, but this does not remove the variables with zero values from the URL. Think about why you want to do this. It is far more reasonable to this processing on the receiving end.

---

I'm assuming you meant to use GET not POST

Answer (score 0):

For your default selections (the ones that don't count) set the value attribute to "". I believe this will indicate to the browser to not send that data along.

```
<select name="select1">
    <option value="">Default Selection</option>
    <option value="X">First option</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Would it not pass `result.php?Model=&somethingelse=`?

Comment: may depend on the browser... but i think normally it also sends empty values.